# Can I replace the $\frac{d}{dt}$ with $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ in the Leibniz integral rule?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, leibniz-integral-rule

Leibniz integral rule can be applied like following if $N$ is a function of $t$

$$
\frac{dN}{dt} =\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}\rho(x,t)dx\right)
$$

$$
\frac{dN}{dt} =\int_a^b \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}dx+
\rho(b,t)\frac{db}{dt}-\rho(a,t)\frac{da}{dt}
$$

Now, if $N$ is a function of $x$ and $t$, what will the Leibniz integral rule look like?

I think it will be like this, am I right?

$$
\frac{\partial N}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left(\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}\rho(x,t)dx\right)
$$

$$
\frac{\partial N}{\partial t} = \int_a^b \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}dx+
\rho(b,t)\frac{\partial b}{\partial t}-\rho(a,t)\frac{\partial a}{\partial t}
$$

Comment: Do you mean when the limits involve other variables like $a(t,u,v)$? Why not? By the way you have got a $\frac{dN}{dt}$ on both sides of the first and third equation, you'd better correct the question.

Comment: In the given example $N$ only depends on one variable $(t)$ so it's partial derivative equals its regular derivative.

Comment: Downvoted. Start by explicitly stating what $N$ is -- making people figure it out is inconsiderate. Also, please make the fixes pointed out by @ancientmathematician.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ cannot depend on $x$, because it is the integration variable

Answer (score 1):

Let's expand the right-hand side:
$$\frac{\partial N}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left[R(b(t), t) - R(a(t), t)\right], ~~~~\text{ where } \frac{\partial R}{\partial x} = \rho(x, t)$$
Continuing to simplify the right-hand side, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial N}{\partial t} &= \frac{\partial b}{\partial t} \cdot \frac{\partial R}{\partial x}(b(t), t) + \frac{\partial R}{\partial t}(b(t), t) - \frac{\partial a}{\partial t} \cdot \frac{\partial R}{\partial x}(a(t), t) -\frac{\partial R}{\partial t}(a(t), t) \\ \\
&= [b'(t) \cdot \rho(b(t), t) - a'(t) \cdot \rho(a(t), t)] + \left[\frac{\partial R}{\partial t}(b(t), t) - \frac{\partial R}{\partial t}(a(t), t)\right] \\ \\
&= [b'(t) \cdot \rho(b(t), t) - a'(t) \cdot \rho(a(t), t)] + \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \frac{\partial^2 R}{\partial x \partial t}(x, t)~ dx
\end{align*}
And assuming the function $R$ is smooth enough to have mixed partials be equivalent (see [Clairaut Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives)), the integral can be simplified and the resulting expression is
$$[b'(t) \cdot \rho(b(t), t) - a'(t) \cdot \rho(a(t), t)] + \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} 
 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial R}{\partial x}(x, t)~ dx \\ = [b'(t) \cdot \rho(b(t), t) - a'(t) \cdot \rho(a(t), t)] + \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} 
 \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}(x, t) ~ dx$$
So the answer to your question is yes! Now if you'd be a little keener than me, you'd have notice of course this must be the case, because the value $N$ is actually only a function of $t$, so of course $dN / dt = \partial N / \partial t$... (Recall $a$ and $b$ are also only functions of $t$, so their partial derivatives are also their total derivatives.)

Comment: Could you explain how you got $ \frac {\partial R} {\partial x} $?